# applying a new library dependancy in android studio project structure

Tags: android

I have a problem with applying a new library dependancy in Project struction.

on the lesson to learn how to use google map,

Project Structure -> Module -> app -> dependancy -> library dependancy

I faced

a NoClassDefFoundError : Could not initialize classcom.android.tools.idea.structure.gradle.MavenDependencyLookupDialog

Any suggestion or feedback will be appreciated

Thank you.

my build.gradle is like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.googlemap.googlemapdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'}
```

Comment: Did you add in gradle file?

Comment: please add your build.gradle code

Comment: show us code on how your implement it